# trying to use lumberjack in a project that includes a library that also uses lumberjack

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods, cocoalumberjack

i'm currently using [skyepub](http://skyepub.net/) as a library to include an e-reader in my app. After following the instructions and trying to install [lumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack), i'm getting a compile error complaining that lumberjack was already included in skyepub.. and so i can't use it in my project! how do i handle this?

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDASLLogger in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDASLLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDASLLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DDASLLogger in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDASLLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDASLLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_DDLogFileManagerDefault._logsDirectory in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDFileLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDFileLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLogFileFormatterDefault in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDFileLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDFileLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DDLogFileFormatterDefault in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDFileLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDFileLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLogFileManagerDefault in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDFileLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDFileLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DDLogFileManagerDefault in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDFileLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDFileLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDFileLogger in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDFileLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDFileLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DDFileLogger in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDFileLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDFileLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_DDFileLogger.logFileManager in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDFileLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDFileLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLogFileInfo in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDFileLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDFileLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DDLogFileInfo in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDFileLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDFileLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_DDLogFileInfo.filePath in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDFileLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDFileLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDAbstractLogger in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDLog.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDLog.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DDAbstractLogger in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDLog.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDLog.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLog in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDLog.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDLog.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DDLog in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDLog.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDLog.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLogMessage in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDLog.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDLog.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DDLogMessage in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDLog.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDLog.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDTTYLogger in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDTTYLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDTTYLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DDTTYLogger in: 
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aj-felgyoujugchfheepjnjfvwvmjcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLumberjack.a(DDTTYLogger.o)
    /Users/me/dev/ios/aj-iOS/aj/Libraries/SkyEpub/libskyepub.a(DDTTYLogger.o)
ld: 21 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

## update

content of pod file

```
platform :ios, "7.1"

target "some_target" do

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
pod 'ODRefreshControl', '~> 1.1'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.2'
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 1.12'
pod 'DYRateView', '~> 0.0.2'
pod 'STTwitter', '~>0.2.2'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '0.9'
pod 'SZTextView', '~> 1.2'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.10'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'objective-zip', :git => 'https://github.com/lobolabs/Objective-Zip'
pod 'FMDB/SQLCipher',:git => 'https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb.git'
pod 'LKDBHelper',:git => 'https://github.com/li6185377/LKDBHelper-SQLite-ORM.git'
pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.5.7'
pod 'RealReachability', '~> 1.1'

end
```

Comment: Did you try not to include Lumberjack in your project explicitly? It should be imported anyway from the SkyEpub.

Comment: Can you please show us the content of your Podfile? I think you need to set the dependency properly.

Comment: @DavidCheung done, question updated

Comment: Since you did not use cocoapod for skyepub, I think you better create a podspec for it and set it depends on cocoalumberjack.

Comment: @DavidCheung that's nice.. can you show me an example code or where i can find instructions to set such dependency in a pod spec? i've never written a podspec before in my life

Comment: Please check the documentation from cocoapods: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency

Comment: @DavidCheung i've contacted the skeypub team to do a podspec themselves.. my client won't be paying me to do a podspec for skyepub :p